# jQuery - Regular Expression Problem - get href address between 3 '/' (slashes)

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I retrieve `/admin/articles/` from `/admin/articles/add` using regular expression and jQuery?

I already have the following jQuery code setup, but need help with Regular Expressions

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var path = "/" + location.pathname.substring(1);

        //Need regular expession here to make 'path' per the above mentioned example

        if ( path ) {
            $('#idlist a[href$="' + path + '"]').parent().attr('class','active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: is this your exact reuirement. i mean, do have `location.pathaname` with more than there slashes?

Comment: Yeah... that would be my exact reqs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var path = location.pathname.replace (/^(\/.+?\/.+?\/).+$/, '$1');
```

Turns `'/admin/articles/add'` into `'/admin/articles/'`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed... Excellent Brock.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract **/admin/articles/** from **/admin/articles/add** there is no need to use jquery or regex.

Try this.

```
var str ="/admin/articles/add";
var extracted = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: This fails if there is any path after the "add".  For example, pagination: `str ="/admin/articles/add/2";`

Comment: @Brock: I know. Thats why added the first line to the answer.

Comment: `"Thats why added the first line to the answer"` -- I don't get what you mean.  Anyway, your answer will probably work for the OP *now*, but I was just pointing out that it's prone to easy breakage, when something changes.

Comment: @Brock: I got it. i have asked clarification in my comment to question.

Comment: This works as well..thanks. However, Brock's is more aligned to what will happen if anything is added to the domain besides what I asked for.